# Can't modify the list return by ibatis? (throws UnsupportedOperationException)

Tags: java, ibatis

I select a list of ids from database via ibatis, but when try to `add` a new element, it throw a unsupported exception.

Is the list return by ibatis is final or immutable?

Comment: It's not final: final is a property of a *variable*, and _not_ that of an object. It merely prevents the variable from being re-assigned to. The list *object* is immutable, and this is achieved by throwing an exception when trying to mutate it. (The other meanings of final are irrelevant here.)

Comment: @pst Throwing an exception does not achieve immutability.  A buggy implementation could add the new element and then throw an exception.  Or an alternative implementation could silently do nothing.  Throwing the exception is just a signal.

Comment: @emory yes. the implementation of the List has do nothing here, the stack show, the last call is from AbstracList public void add(int index, E element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is **a read only list and may be backed by a database cursor** that reads and caches as you iterate over the list. Before you can manipulate your data you should copy it.

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
ids.addAll( ibatusIds );
```

Comment: is there more details about "may be backed by a database cursor"?

Comment: Just that most ORM's do that. I don't know about ibatis specifically.